# Less compiling results differ linux vs windows?

Tags: css, linux, windows, less

I have been contributing to a small open source project and found that when I used lessc (compiler) and prettier on windows 10 build 19043,

I got a significantly different result (final css file) than on ubuntu 20.04.

This google slides ([link][1]) documents the 2 intentional changes to the lessc file, then the 91 unintentional changes after running the compiler (resulting from lessc and prettier)

after running the exact same compile process on ubuntu, I got only the 2 intentional changes and nothing extra. My intentional changes are documented in a pull request here: [link][2]

These are the project dependencies from the .json file.

```
"devDependencies": {
    "axios": ">=0.21.1",
    "clean-css-cli": "^4.3.0",
    "concurrently": "^5.3.0",
    "less": "^3.13.1",
    "less-watch-compiler": "^1.15.1",
    "lessc": "^1.0.2",
    "lite-server": "^2.6.1",
    "minimist": "^1.2.3",
    "node-less": "^1.0.0",
    "object-path": ">=0.11.5",
    "onchange": "^7.1.0",
    "prettier": "^2.3.0"
```

Any idea why lessc or prettier would compile differently on linux vs windows? I am new to all this so forgive me if I've missed something obvious, thanks!

edit: I added 2 links, 1 for the windows errors and the 2nd with the correct linux output.

Thanks for the help!
[1]: https://docs.google.com/presentation/d/1dGjp5UEpkk4apojAtlNQg5hb2wktTKOgROU08sUN1OM/edit?usp=sharing
[2]: https://github.com/sButtons/sbuttons/pull/1397/commits/b1b1d6ddb3c15780e1fb3309fd637f3eec426106

Comment: Re: "significantly different result[s]" - can you edit your question to elaborate on this, perhaps include some image links of the different results?

Comment: Hi John, I made the edits. Thanks for the feedback. This is my first post so I'm still figuring out what makes a good question.